# Usage of demzufolge and deshalb

Tags: adverb

Do *demzufolge* and *deshalb* have the same meaning? Here are a couple of sentences :

1. Ich lerne Deutsch, deshalb bin ich in Deutschland.
2. Ich lerne Deutsch, demzufolge bin ich in Deutschland.

Comment: @c.p. That would not be very good dictionaries.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz [duden lists them](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/demzufolge) [as synonyms](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/deshalb)

Comment: @Vogel612 Then I will have to disagree with Duden. To me “folglich” and “infolgedessen” (taken from the Duden list) are not synonymous, with “folglich” belonging to “demzufolge” group and “infolgedessen” to “deshalb”.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz poor duden ;) I think synonymous does not mean "the same" they both reflect causality and thus can be interchanged with little effort. listing them as synonymous thus is correct. or am i wrong here?

Comment: @Vogel612 You are right. Wikipedia: „Insbesondere verschiedene Wörter mit gleicher oder ähnlicher Bedeutung sind Synonyme zueinander, sie stehen in der Relation der Synonymie oder Bedeutungs-, Sinn- oder Verwendungsgleichheit, -ähnlichkeit oder -verwandtschaft.“ Verwandtschaft lässt sich ihnen nicht absprechen. Damit wären sie wohl synonym, aber nicht bedeutungsgleich. Ich dachte, „synonym“ wäre nicht nur synonym, sondern bedeutungsgleich mit „bedeutungsgleich“.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... I actually thought so too and I think many if not most people think that. At least when it comes to a foreign language. 2 words are synonymous? All right, so I can exchange one for the other all the time. ... source of much confusion.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Note, that you will find examples in which those two words are possible. "Ich bin kein amerikanischer Bürger und darf demzufolge[=deshalb] auch nicht an Wahlen in den USA teilnehmen." - "Sie hat ihre Abiturprüfung nicht bestanden und durfte demzufolge[=deshalb] nicht ihr Studium antreten."

Comment: The "argument from the dictionary" is a special type of fallacy :-)

Comment: @Em1, good point, if A always implies B then the point is moot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*deshalb*:

- aus diesem Grund – because of that
- die Folge aus dem zuvor Gesagten – the subsequent result of what just has been said
- aus A folgt B – B follows A

> Er ist krank. Deshalb kann er nicht kommen. (= Weil er krank ist, kann er nicht kommen.)

*demzufolge*:

- demnach, folglich – as a consequence
- logische Konsequenz – logical consequence
- aus A erschließt sich B – B is deduced from A

> Vegetarier essen kein Fleisch. Ich esse kein Fleisch. Demzufolge bin ich Vegetarier. (= Weil die Aussage auch auf mich zutrifft, muss ich logischerweise auch Vegetarier sein.)

Addendum:
In respect to comments, I'd like to mention that it is not necessary to have two explicit statements in order to use *demzufolge*. However, there's an implicit statement given. Here's an example in which use can use both *deshalb* and *demzufolge*:

> Sie hat ihre Abiturprüfung nicht bestanden und durfte demzufolge [=deshalb] nicht ihr Studium antreten.

- Because she failed, the subsequent result is that she's not allowed to study -> *deshalb*
- Because it's necessary to pass your A-levels exam in order to matriculate and because she doesn't passed them, the logical consequence is that she's not allowed to study -> *demzufolge*

Again, you use *demzufolge* whenever B is a deduction of A. You go with *deshalb* whenever B is just a subsequent result of A.

Comment: Braucht man eigentlich zwei Behauptungen, um *demzufolge* nutzen zu können? Ich glaube, dass z.B. im ersten Satz ist auch stillschweigend, dass "sich kranke Menschen nicht so einfach bewegen und in die Arbeit oder wohin auch immer gehen können". Daher ist *deshalb* auch durch demzufogle *ersetzbar*. Der Unterschied ist mir noch nicht klar. Braucht dann *demzufolge* explizit ein "aus A folgt B" und "aus B folgt C", **demzufolge** "folgt C aus A"?

Comment: @c.p. Nein, es ist nicht notwendig, diese explicit zu nennen. Für Details siehe meine überarbeitete Antwort.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is not quite the same.

> A, deshalb B

means that A causes B.

> A, demzufolge B

means that we can deduce B from A. At least that seems to me to be the main usage, others may disagree.

In your question, (2) does not seem right, since there are many people who learn German without being in Germany. (1) would mean something like

> Ich bin in Deutschland, weil ich Deutsch lerne.

That is not quite right. More to the point would be

> Ich bin in Deutschland, weil ich Deutsch lernen möchte.

and hence

> Ich möchte Deutsch lernen, deshalb bin ich in Deutschland.

Another good alternative to (1) is

> Ich lerne Deutsch, zu diesem Zweck bin ich in Deutschland.

Shorter for “zu diesem Zweck” would be “dazu”.

Comment: zu diesem Zweck: warum nicht *"dazu"*?

Comment: @Vogel612 Weil es mir nicht eingefallen ist ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that "*demzufolge*" could be best translated as "*consequently*", while "*deshalb*" could be best translated as "*therefore*".