# How to use "weil" properly

Tags: word-order

I want to say: because aerospace is my favorite area/field, therefore...

Is there any difference between these two sentences?

> Weil meine Lieblingsgebiete/felder Luft und Raumfahrt sind, deshalb...

or

> Weil Luft und Raumfahrt meine Lieblingsgebiete/felder sind, deshalb...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question about word order](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23822/question-about-word-order)

Comment: The first part in both sentences are fine (Lieblingsgebiet is a noun and has to be written with a capital L), but the `deshalb` sounds strange.

Comment: @chirlu I'm sure this has been asked a handful of times, being indeed a dupe, but the link you gave is not the right one.

Comment: I agree with @c.p. and add that I think that the same holds for “because” and “therefore”.

Comment: @c.p.: Feel free to find a better duplicate. :-)

Comment: @raznagul Z.B : deshalb ich lerne Luft und Raumfahrttechnik... does it still sound strange ?.

Comment: In your specific example I would use "da" instead of "weil". It's not wrong though, just sounds better in my opinion. Just like "because" and "since"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both cojunctions *deshalb* and *weil* are used to initiate a causal clause:

> Ich bin müde, **weil** ich nicht genug geschlafen habe.
>   Ich habe nicht genug geschlafen, **deshalb** bin ich müde.

In these examples we use one or the other. Sentence order does not matter for *weil*, as we can also say:

> **Weil** ich nicht genug geschlafen habe, bin ich müde.

However, different to *weil* putting *deshalb* at the beginning of a sentence would be very unusual.

For emphasis we can also combine the use of *deshalb* and *weil*. If we do then *deshalb* must be correlated with a *weil* sentence.

> Ich bin **deshalb** müde, **weil** ich nicht genug geschlafen habe.

So in case you want to use both in your example sentence it could go like this:

> Mein Lieblingsgebiet ist deshalb Luft- und Raumfahrttechnik, weil *mein Vater Astronaut ist*.

Also see:

- [Usage of demzufolge and deshalb](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8363/usage-of-demzufolge-and-deshalb)
- [Warum wird "weil" zur nebenordnenden Konjunktion?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6339/warum-wird-weil-zur-nebenordnenden-konjunktion)
- [Question about word order](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23822/question-about-word-order)

Comment: _**Darum** lieb ich alles was so grün ist, **weil** mein Schatz ein Jäger ist_ – Unusual indeed, but not impossible, at least in lyrics. Note that you can usually substitute _darum_ and _deshalb_ for each other when used as conjunctions, but _ich bin **?darum** müde, **weil** …_ would be questionable at least.